# В первый раз долго загружается Activity

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, activity, android-intent

На MainActivity есть кнопка при нажатии на которую происходит переход на другое Activity.

При первом переходе всё подвисает и только потом переходит. Если опять вернуться на стартовое Activity, то при следующих переходах всё загружается мгновенно. Второе Activity состоит из нескольких EditText.

Как сделать так чтобы второе Activity сразу загружалось в стек при запуске приложения, и потом мгновенно открывалось по клику?

```
public class WelcomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.welcome_layout);

        TextView reg_btn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome_reg_btn);
        reg_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.register_layout);
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавьте код `RegisterActivity`.

Comment: @post_zeew добавил

Comment: А какое у вас устройство и какая версия андроида?

Comment: @post_zeew nexus 5 android 6.0

Comment: Ответа нету?)..